# ie9 placeholder text shouldn't allow submit on required field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to figure out how to get a validation to work on ie9 placeholder text. I'm aware that ie9 doesn't support placeholders and thats my issue. My work around for that is to simply see what the placeholder is and input that value but I want don't want the form to submit with that value.

```
function form_modal_validate(id){
  // function used for client validation for forms inside a modal
  var form = $(id);
  $('.field_error, .label_error').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('field_error').removeClass('label_error');
  });

  phoneValidation();
  var placeholders = {};
  form.validate({
    errorClass: 'field_error',
    errorElement: 'none',
    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
      return true;
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(form).find(':input[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        placeholders[placeholder] = this;
        $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
      });
      form.submit();
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
      $.each(placeholders, function(placeholder, element) {
        $(element).attr('placeholder', placeholder);
      });
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      // overwrite highlight methods to add class to label as well as the input itself
      $(element).closest('.modal_input').find('.modal_label label').addClass("label_error");
      $(element).closest('dl.left, dl').find('dt label').addClass("label_error");
      $(element).addClass('field_error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.modal_input').find('.modal_label label').removeClass("label_error");
      $(element).closest('dl.left, dl').find('dt label').removeClass("label_error");
      $(element).removeClass('field_error');
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the code I'm working with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your workaround is the root of what's lacking or broken.  Essentially, the fake "placeholder" value needs to be dynamically toggled in order for validation to work properly.  Update your OP with the ***relevant*** HTML markup of the form.

Comment: How would you go about that?